# Why does this piece of code only plot the last plot of the for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

In Rstudio I want to plot 7 plots, each for a timepoint. I do have 2 dataframes in which I have for all 7 timepoints de values of one axis.

my code:

```
#3.4.4 plotting ma plots
FIG2 <- par(mfrow = c(4,2))
for (i in 1:7)
    main = paste('MA-plot for timepoint ',i, sep ='')
    plot(averageratio[[paste('A',i,sep='')]],
         intensityratio[[paste('M',i,sep='')]], main = main, 
         xlab='average log intensity', ylab='log intensity ratio')
    abline(0, 0, lwd=2.5, col='blue', lty=2)
```

Now this only shows me the last plot of timepoint 7, but I want all of them.

Comment: Put the lines in the for-loop inside {}. At the moment all your script does is count from 1 to 7, and then run the remaining lines once with i=7.

Comment: Damn, that was simple. Thank you!=)